# ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonMerge when starting Spark

Tags: apache-spark, jackson

While there are many similar errors with Spark I am still at a loss how to fix the following. Note that I do not have any  `Jackson` maven entries: only the `Spark` that pulls in jackson as transitive dependencies:

```
19/07/14 17:42:49 ERROR MetricsSystem: Sink class org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.MetricsServlet cannot be instantiated
19/07/14 17:42:49 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSinks$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSinks$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.registerSinks(MetricsSystem.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.start(MetricsSystem.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:514)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        ..
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:131)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonMerge
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.<clinit>(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:50)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:291)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.MetricsServlet.<init>(MetricsServlet.scala:48)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonMerge
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 44 more
```

The only reference to jackson *at all* is in an AWS but it is an *exclusion* :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
       <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

How can this `jackson` issue (probably a versioning) be resolved? Note: I have tried with Spark 2.4.2 and then downgraded to 2.3.0: same errors. I can not downgrade more than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added following to the `pom.xml`. Have no idea why this dependency were not pulled in automatically

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Note : You might also uncounter the same issue with Zeppelin on AWS. Unfortunetaly, Zeppelin returns a NullPointerException.